# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit"

Tags: postgresql

when I am using this command to update table in PostgreSQL 13:

```
UPDATE rss_sub_source 
SET sub_url = SUBSTRING(sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(sub_url) - 1) 
WHERE sub_url LIKE '%/'
limit 10
```

but shows this error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit"
  Position: 111
```

why would this error happen and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) there is no LIMIT for an UPDATE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` isn't a valid keyword in an `UPDATE` statement according to the official PostgreSQL documentation:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = [ ROW ] ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
        } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_item [, ...] ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

<sup>***Reference:** [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) (PostgreSQL Documentation )*</sup>

#### Solution

Remove `LIMIT 10` from your statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could make something like this

But a Limit without an ORDER BY makes no sense, so you must choose one that gets you the correct 10 rows

```
UPDATE rss_sub_source t1
SET t1.sub_url = SUBSTRING(t1.sub_url, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(t1.sub_url) - 1) 
FROM (SELECT id FROM rss_sub_source WHERE sub_url LIKE '%/' ORDER BY id LIMIT 10) t2 
WHERE t2.id = t1.id
```